# How to delete a class file from maven dependency manually using eclipse ide. Delete option is not available in IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

[image: delete option not available]

If manual delete option is not available. Please help with easy alternate methods.

Comment: You can't really do that. Why do you want to?

Comment: i want to delete a class in log4j dependency which is having a vulnerability. I have updated the screenshot

Comment: Which version of log4j are you on? Can you upgrade to 2.15.0?

Comment: i am using 1.2.16. I am looking for a solution without upgrading to 2.15.0

Comment: So this isn't CVE-2021-44228. Which vulnerability?

Comment: A flaw was found in the Java logging library Apache Log4j in version 1.x. JMSAppender in Log4j 1.x is vulnerable to deserialization of untrusted data. This allows a remote attacker to execute code on the server if the deployed application is configured to use JMSAppender and to the attacker's JMS Broker. Check this link https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2021-4104

Comment: You can remove the class from the jar (see the suggested command line at that link), add the new jar to your project's version control, and then change the scope of the dependency to `system`.

Comment: i have used the command . But it did not work. I am using windows os. Installed 7 zip , set the environment variable and executed the command in cmd. but zip was not  recognized.

Comment: Are you actually using/configuring JMSAppender?  The vulnerability you are concerned about is only pertinent when JMSAppender is being used in the implementing application.  Since you are saying you simply want to delete it, this makes me think you aren't actually using it so there shouldn't be a vulnerability.

Comment: its in target folder right? for delete the file you go to the folder location

Comment: "But it did not work" -- in what way *exactly*?

Comment: @tgdavies 'zip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Getting this error

Comment: @Michael i am not using JMS appender log4j.properties file. but a package in log4j is having that class.

Comment: @SoniyaMohan cannot open that class via file explorer

Comment: That's a problem with how you have installed the zip program, perhaps it hasn't been added to your path.

Comment: @tgdavies C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe i have added this path in environment variables under system variables section. I am using 7zip

Comment: In the Windows _File Explorer_ right-click the file, choose _7-Zip > Open_ and in the 7-Zip application navigate to the file and delete it.

Comment: @howlger it is not possible to find the desired class through the file explorer

Comment: The location of the desired JAR file is shown in Eclipse (it is cropped in your screenshot of your outdated Eclipse), so it should be possible for you to find it.

Comment: @howlger i am looking for a class named JMSAppender.class inside package org.apache.log4j.net which is inside log4j-1.2.16.jar. I cannot navigate to the desired class through eclipse or through file explorer. If you right click on desired class and click on properties , it is not possible to get desired class file location

Comment: Sure, you have to use for example the 7-Zip application to open the JAR (right-click the `log4j-1.2.16.jar` and choose _7-Zip > Open_) and then navigate to the .class file. Alternative, to use the Windows File Explorer, you have to rename the .jar file to .zip first.

Comment: @howlger using the above mentioned method i was able to delete the class . Thank you so much

Comment: @cyrilgeorge153 sounds like you got it addressed through removal.  If you read the vulnerability report, it is only a vulnerability if the JMSAppender is configured and used so removing it is a bit of overkill if you aren't using it, but you achieved your desired result.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the dependencies from `pom.xml` file to remove the injected dependencies

Comment: The question asks about removing a single class from a dependency.